# Euclidean norm gives length even in $>3$ dimensions?

Tags: geometry, vectors, normed-spaces

In $1,2,3$ dimensions I can simply make triangles and see that Euclidean norm gives me the distance between two points (i.e. the length of the vector from one point to the other). In higher dimensions, though, how do we know that the euclidean norm still represents a length? It makes sense that we could still decompose the vector between the points into multiple triangles, but how are we sure that things don't become weird -- i.e. decomposition into triangles becomes invalid -- in $4,5,6$ dimensions?

In other words, I am wondering if there is either a proof (or if someone can supply a proof), or just some really good intuition why the euclidean norm continues to be a way of finding the length between two points in higher dimensions.

Comment: The question is: what is "length" in $\Bbb R^n$? The bigger question then is: what is $\Bbb R^n$? It's not longer a physical entity is it (as far as I know). So why must it accommodate a notion of length?

Comment: Fair point, but the reason I ask this question is because I think "norm" is often used as "length", even in $n$ dimensions. If either length or the euclidean norm don't make sense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then norm wouldn't be used as such, unless it is being used incorrectly (which is also a valid answer).

Comment: to define either $R^n$ or a length in $R^n$ certain axioms must be defined.  $R^n$, so far I know, is defined to be the set of n-tuples reals (i.e. a cross product) with any projection to a lower dimension by restiriction one dimension holds as an n-1 space. The 4 norm of (x,y,w,z) is a result of the 3 norm on (x,y,w.0) and (x,y,0,z) (or whatever).

Comment: Consider a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ and check that it works there.  Then notice that **every** vector in $\Bbb R^n$ can be said to exist in a $3$-dimensional subspace (or in fact a $2$- or even $1$-dimensional subspace).

Comment: Defining length in R1, R2 or R3 in math doesn't have any more or less "natural" meaning than any other axiom. And the axioms of R4+ are no less unnatural.  The length of R4+ can't get "weird" because there is no natural state for them to exist in to be "weird" in comparison to.  length *doesn't* have to be the euclidean norm in R^2 and we can easily and frequently do define length in R^2 *very* differently.

Comment: The distance between (a,b,c,d) and (e,f,g,d) is calculatable because they both exist in the same 3 space. (x, y,z, d).  And the distance between (a,b,c,d) and (e,f,c,h) is calculatable because the both exist in the same 3 space (x,y,c,z).  Those two lines exist in a 2 d plain and we can find the distance between (a,b,c,d) and (e,f,g,h) because they are both in the plane.

Comment: Recommended reading: Definitions of 1.Metric space .2.Normed vector space. 3. Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.  5. Inner product, and Inner -Product- Space. 4. Hilbert space.

Comment: Distance is not an absolute concept; to make a different example, a square in a chessboard can be quite far for a King, but at a single move distance for a Knight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments already pointed out, you can't have a physical space with more than 3 spatial dimensions. So the concept of length as something which can be measured with a ruler breaks down. You can simply continue to use the term “length” for the norm, since it helps intuition, it is compatible with everyday experience in lower dimensions and there is no higher-dimension reality which could conflict with this. But it's essentially just a colloquial alias for “norm”.

Regarding your triangles considerations: for any dimension greater than one, one can compute the length/norm by breaking the distance down into one component parallel to one of the coordinate directions, and one component perpendicular to it. The former is a one-dimensional length, the latter a $(n-1)$-dimensional one, so you can recurse until you end up in a space of dimension $\le3$. The problem with this is that the concept of orthogonality in higher dimensions has about as much justification as that of length: we simply call things orthogonal if the dot product is zero, even though we couldn't verify it's actually perpendicular by holding a set square to it.

All of the above assumes a simple $\mathbb R^n$. There are spaces which have very different ideas of length, distance and/or norm. [The comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621967/euclidean-norm-gives-length-even-in-3-dimensions#comment3307061_1621967) by [user254665](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/254665/user254665) points out some such spaces, which I repeat with links to Wikipedia and some summary:

1. A [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) has a defined way to measure distances, not neccessarily using a norm. Perhaps it would be more correct above to say that “length” is a colloquial term for “distance as computed by the metric”, but for everiday applications it's the same.
2. A [normed vectorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) has a defined norm, which in turn implies a metric.
3. An [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) is a vector space which comes with a defined inner product. There the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) holds, which is a generalized triangle inequality.
4. A [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) is an inner product space which is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) with respect to the metric induced by that inner product.

Comment: This answer is acceptable to me, and also clearly explained. However, I wish to bring up that, for $1,2$, can't you (and don't people) have metric spaces and vector spaces where the norm or the metric correspond to/are an extension of euclidean distance is 2 or 3 dimensions? More specifically, is that not the point of the Euclidean norm and Euclidean metric? I simply do not think norms  should be called "length" when discussing higher dimensions unless the usage of the term "length" can be justified.

Comment: @majmun: To see whether I understand you correctly: You are worried whether there exist metric spaces of dimension $n>3$ where (a) the metric on the whole space is *not* the Euclidean norm and (b) the metric of every 2 or 3-dimensional subspace *is* identical to the Euclidean norm. Is that it? If so, I guess it depends on how you define Euclidean norm without a reference to plain $\mathbb R^n$. I know of no situation where calling the norm length would be ambiguous, even without further justification than extrapolation from known situations.

Comment: I think it's all a matter of context, and of how well you know your audience. I know little of exotic normed vectorspaces, but I do know a bit about [Minkowski spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space). I have observed myself and others to use the term “scalar product” for the inner product there, even though it's not positive definite, simply because it's conventient. As long as the audience knows the subject to not associate incorrect properties with this use of the term, that's fine. Similarly, if the audience knows length to be a synonym for norm, that's fine.